# Select-max() value in codeigniter work wrong with two or more character

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have below table and I want to select_max value from Pro_id it is work if I used 1 digit of pro_id character

```
+----+--------------------------+------------+
| id | pro_id                   | parent     |
+----+--------------------------+------------+
|  3 | 1                        |         19 |
|  4 | 2                        |         18 |
|  5 | 3                        |         19 |
|  6 | 4                        |         34 |
+----+--------------------------+------------+
```

But it is not work if I used two or more digit for pro_id as below table

```
+----+--------------------------+------------+
| id | pro_id                   | parent     |
+----+--------------------------+------------+
|  3 | 1352                     |         19 |
|  4 | 244                      |         18 |
|  5 | 32                       |         19 |
|  6 | 4455                     |         34 |
+----+--------------------------+------------+
```

How can I do with select_max in Codeigniter because I want to select maximum value from column pro_id But it not work for me

Comment: `pro_id` needs to be a numeric type.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your pro_id declared as varchar not int.
This query convert varchar to integer.

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(proid AS UNSIGNED)) AS proid FROM PRODUCT
```

Comment: this issue with mine was varchar not in int, so i had to cast it as the answer says

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select * from your_table order by pro_id desc limit 1
```

Comment: $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('invoice');
  $this->db->order_by("in_no", "desc");
  $this->db->limit(1);
  $this->db->where('status',1);
  $this->query =  $this->db->get();
  if($this->query->num_rows()>0){
   return $this->query->result();
  }

I've used this but still now owrk

Comment: Hi there, This may well solve the problem - but it would be good if you could explain why/how it solves the problem. You may not know, but there are heaps of rank newbies on S/O and they could learn a  thing or two from your expertise. What may be really obvious to you may not be so to them. So please edit your answer and add a line or two explaining what you changed and why the change works.

Answer (score 0):

convert the `prod_id` field to integer i.e. a numeric field.

```
$sql = "select max(pro_id+0) from DB_TABLE";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```